# Estimating size of minimum vertex cover from randomly sampled subgraph

Tags: statistics, graph-theory, algorithms, sampling, random-graphs

I would like to estimate the **size** of the *minimum vertex cover* (MVC) for a very large graph $G=(V,E)$. To be exact, I would like to estimate the following proportion:

$$p(G)=\frac{|MVC|_G}{|V|}$$

As computing a MVC is quite expensive, I want to sample a subgraph $G_s=(V',E')$ with $n$ vertices from $G$ and compute $p(G')$. Finally, my goal is to estimate $p(G)$ from $p(G')$ with some error and/or confidence depending on $n$.

After a lot of research, I wasn't able to get a convincing result and almost no literature. I linked this problem to the estimation of the *independence number* but, once again, its estimation from a randomly sampled subgraph is absent.

I'm open on any parameter of the problem and if you have even a small idea of a potentially interesting paper to read, I am all ears. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know anything about the graph $G$?

Comment: No, I can assume nothing about the graph. 

The graph generation process is very costly and this is why my goal is to compute only a part of this full graph ($G_s$). Then, I want to extend the result to the rest of the graph ($G$) which is unknown. Actually, if I knew the full graph directly, I could apply classic MVC approximations so this is why I focus on this random sampling technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the very good explanation from Misha, I am just going to give my feedbacks after finding sufficient results for my application. Multiple papers have been published on the subject proposing to estimate the the MVC size from only a fraction of the nodes (they call it *sublinear* as it is sublinear regarding the number of nodes). In chronological order, here are the one you want to take a look at:

- *Approximating the minimum vertex cover in sublinear time and a connection to distributed algorithms*, Parnas and Ron (2007)
- *Constant-Time Approximation Algorithms via Local Improvements*, Nguyen and Onak (2008)
- *An improved constant-time approximation algorithm for maximum~matchings*, Yoshida and Yamamoto (2009)
- *A Near-Optimal Sublinear-Time Algorithm for Approximating the Minimum Vertex Cover Size*, Onak and Ron (2011)

They have been one the road of improving successively both the complexity of the algorithm and the quality of the approximation. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If there exists a vertex cover $U$ of order $|U| = p(G) |V|$, then any subgraph of size $n$ is going to see $p(G) n$ of $U$'s vertices in expectation, and this is tightly concentrated, central limit theorem and all. This means $p(G_s) \lessapprox p(G)$; we can work out what the bounds look like, but they're not the big problem here.

The big problem is that $G_s$ could have a really good vertex cover that does not come from $U$. To give one bad example, suppose $G$ is the cycle $C_N$, with $p(G) = \frac12$. Then a random sample of $n$ vertices contains a fixed edge with probability $\binom{N-2}{n-2}/\binom Nn = \frac{n(n-1)}{N(N-1)}$, so the expected number of edges is $\frac{n(n-1)}{N-1}$.

For $n \ll \sqrt{N}$, we'll see none of the edges of $G$, and get $p(G_s) = 0$, with high probability. By a similar calculation, for $n \ll N^{2/3}$, we'll just see a bunch of isolated edges and isolated vertices; in this range, the expected size of a vertex cover of $G_s$ is just the expected number of edges, and the expected value of $p(G_s)$ is about $\frac{n-1}{N-1}$, which is tiny. We see similar behavior for all $n \ll N$.

Even for $n = \frac12 N$, which is ridiculous as a sampling strategy, most components of $G_s$ are paths of constant length, and for every path of even length or isolated vertex, we reduce the size of the minimum vertex cover. So $p(G_s)$ is off by a constant from $p(G)$; I compute that more precisely, the expected value of $p(G_s)$ is about $\frac13$, but the actual computation is annoying and doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! What I understand is that random sampling reduces the complexity of the initial graph $G$ (notably the edge density) and creates a sparser graph $G_s$. As by definition a sparser graph will have a lower $|MVC|$, we will have $p(G_s)<p(G)$ with high probability.

It seems that there is no straight forward solution to estimate $p(G)$ from $p(G_s)$... or if so, confidence and error will be up high. 

Thank you again and if anything comes to your mind as alternative solution, I am all hears!

Comment: After further investigation, I am going to look into sublinear distributed algorithms which provide approximations for MVC using a sample of vertices and an oracle!

Comment: Actually, the edge density is **not** reduced. The problem is that in my example, the original graph $G$ has edge density about $\frac 2N$ (and $N$ vertices). The sample $G_s$ also has expected edge density about $\frac 2N$... it just has that edge density on only $n$ vertices, which is very different. If we start with a dense graph $G$ with about $\frac{N^2}{4}$ edges (edge density $\frac12$), then $G_s$ will also have expected edge density $\frac12$. In such cases, $p(G_s)$ might not be much smaller than $p(G)$.